# costmap2d: obstacle layer

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to configure my costmap_common_params.yaml

i look up for the parameters in this wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles

but i am using ros-kinetic not ros-hydro

Is there everything allright? Can i freely use all the parameters described there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330618/costmap2d:-obstacle-layer/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check an example costmap configuration from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Costmap_Configuration_.28local_costmap.29_.26_.28global_costmap.29). Otherwise as far as I can see not much has change and you should be able to use the parameters from the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles) you shared. Hydro and later releases use plugins for all costmap_2d layers.
Also you can always check existing costmap configuration like the [husky_navigation](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel/husky_navigation/config) one.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-08-14**:
thank you,

yes, layers is very important to me